# NSString with lines through each letter

Tags: string, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring, strikethrough

How can I write a string like the following:

> H̶̶o̶̶w̶ ̶t̶̶o̶ ̶w̶̶r̶̶i̶̶t̶̶e̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶i̶̶s̶ ̶t̶̶e̶̶x̶̶t̶

In my app, I need to display the past price of a product that has been replaced by a new price. Like so:

> $̶8̶̶0̶̶0̶   ->   $600

Comment: Look for `NSAttributedString` & `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`

Comment: @Larme Could you tell me more for this, or could you tell me the name for this kind of character. It would be good for me search more. Tks

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh There are strikethrough characters in UTF8. You can use those directly in an Obj-C string. E.g. `@"8̶0̶0̶"`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough#Unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this result you should use NSAttributedString and set the attribute name NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName. The number used as object for this key defines the style of the line over the text.

```
self.myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"800" attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @1}];
```

Cheers

Comment: It seem to easy but my English is not good. This kind of character is "Strikethrough". Tks for your help